# How can i get list of values from object list in Controller

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

Aura Component:

```
 <aura:attribute name="PercentPick" type="string[]" />
            <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<lightning:select aura:id="PicklistId" label="DocumentType" name="percent" >
            <option value="" text="- None -" /> 
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.PercentPick}" var="per">
                <option value="{!per}" text="{!per}" />  
            </aura:iteration>
        </lightning:select>
```

cONTROLLER.JS:

```
    action.setParams({
        "jobId":jobId
    });
    var percent = component.find("PicklistId");
    
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var allValues = response.getReturnValue();
        var picklistvalues=[];
        console.log('allValues -- >> ' + allValues);
        console.dir(allValues);
        component.set("v.PercentPick", allValues);
```

In all values i have array of fields Id,name,Security_Classification__c.i need to get only names into the picklist field

```
Array(2)
0:
Id: "aFS1g0000004ELCGA2"
Name: "dileep -test"
Security_Classification__c: "Company-Public"
__proto__: Object
1:
Id: "aFS1g0000008Pp2GAE"
Name: "dileep 1"
Security_Classification__c: "Company-Public"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.prototype.map for this purpose:

```
component.set("v.PercentPick", allValues.map((value)=>value.Name));
```

I'd avoid doing this unless you can guarantee all the names will be unique, however. It's usually better to make the picklist retain the ID for later use:

```
<aura:attribute name="PercentPick" type="Object[]" />
```

...

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.PercentPick}" var="per">
    <option value="{!per.Id}" text="{!per.Name}" />  
</aura:iteration>
```

Comment: Nope this is not working